# Segmentation fault (Core Dump) while creating stack using pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack

Could you please help me to find out why I'm getting the segmentation fault (Core Dumped) error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack {
    int size;
    int top;
    int *arr;
};

int main(){
struct stack *ptr;
ptr->size = 10; //Code is not going ahead after this line(Segmentation fault)
ptr->top = -1;
ptr->arr = (int *)malloc(ptr->size * sizeof(int));

return 0;
}
```

Trying to create a stack using pointers but while I run this code I m getting this error and I m not able to go ahead without solving this error. Wants to know what is the reason behind it. I read all the reasons for the segmentation error but was not able to solve the error.

Comment: Where does `ptr` point?

Comment: If you turn on all warnings of your compiler you will find out, e.g. gcc says " warning: 'ptr' is used uninitialized"

Comment: malloc returns a void* pointer not int

Comment: # include <stdlib .h>
void * malloc ( size_t size );

Comment: I think initially it's not pointing anywhere.

Comment: Try taking off the (int*) cast ie " = malloc(sizeof size)"

Comment: "I think initially it's not pointing anywhere." and yet you write where it is initially pointing. Spot a problem there?

Comment: Code is not going ahead after this line - ptr->size = 10 .

Comment: @Ritesh ptr does not exist anywhere yet. Therefore ptr->size and every other struct member does not exist anywhere. Therefore trying to set these values will segfault.

Comment: @DoritoJohnson Thank You Very Much for the help! I just got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting segmentation fault because you have no `ptr` allocated.

`ptr` is `struct stack*`, a pointer.

And it was not even initialized.

#### from your code

```
    struct stack* ptr;
    ptr->size = 10;
```

But `ptr` points to what?

#### A safe way:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct st_stack
{
    int  size;
    int  top;
    int* arr;
} Stack;

int main(void)
{
    Stack* ptr = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    ptr->size = 10;
    ptr->top  = -1;
    ptr->arr  = (int*)malloc(ptr->size * sizeof(int));

    free(ptr->arr); // free array
    free(ptr); // free stack

    return 0;
}
```

Note to code police: I **always** cast the return of `malloc()`. Yes, I know about the [C-FAQ](https://C-FAQ.com) from the 90's (never updated). I do this because, as many others, I do no like implicit conversions. For the compiler `void*` is ok. The cast is a reminder **for the programmer** of what is being allocated at each call, and helps to avoid many bugs. `malloc()` accepts any expression that evaluates to a `size_t` and in many cases it is hard to know, in a series of allocations, which is which.

C-FAQ list a big advantage of not using a cast: the compiler will alert you if you forget to `#include stdlib.h`.  Well, if someone needs this kind of reminder there are bigger problems to solve. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining through the code!  Just got my answer that why it's not working. Again Thanks :)